# How to implement generated ApplicationTests in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

There is a generated test class as shown below:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ProductApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

When I leave this, it causes error when I run my unit tests (some errors regarding to not connecting to the database). So, should I delete this class or how to implement it?

Comment: Just remove the `contextLoads` method, you are not gonna need it for now. As for `ProductApplicationTests` let it as you might need it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@SpringBootTest` annotation is for running integration tests. It will create a running application and test it like it would happen in a running instance of your application. As such, you will need to either deactivate the parts of your application that connect to databases/brokers/dependencies (either by mocking them with `@MockBean` or placing them behind configuration flags), or you will need to provide those dependencies and databases.

Generally, it is preferable to alter the program as little as possible when running your tests, so there is a way to create a temporary instance of a database when launching this test, called Testcontainers. Here is a list of databases supported out of the box (the library is extensible too) - https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/ . If you run into issues using it, there is a slack workspace for it, or just create new questions for them.

You can also change the annotation from `@SpringBootTest` to `@WebMvcTest`. The spring guides - https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ - describe this. Basically, it won't try to connect to the database:

> In this test, the full Spring application context is started but without the server. We can narrow the tests to only the web layer by using @WebMvcTest, as the following listing (from src/test/java/com/example/testingweb/WebLayerTest.java) shows:

by narrowing the tests, it is no longer a full integration test, but rather testing parts like a unit test. it also means it doesn't "create" the bottom part of your application (connection to the database, service beans, etc).

---

For example, for this application:

```java
package org.example;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.EnableJdbcRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@EnableJdbcRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservedNameApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
            docker run -d --name local-postgres -p 5432:5432 \
                    -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust \
                    postgres:15-alpine
        */
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url",
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres");
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", "postgres");
        SpringApplication.run(ReservedNameApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner createTables() {
        return args -> {
            try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
                try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                    statement.execute("""
                        create table if not exists hero
                        (
                            id serial,
                            name varchar(100) not null unique
                        );
                        """);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Repository
    interface HeroRepository extends CrudRepository<Hero, Long> {
        Optional<Hero> findByName(String name);
    }

    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @Data
    @Table("hero")
    public static class Hero {
        @Id
        Long id;
        @Column("name")
        String name;
    }

    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @Data
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hero.name-config")
    public static class HeroNameConfig {
        List<String> reservedNames = Arrays.asList("admin", "administrator");
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Service
    public static class HeroService {
        private final HeroRepository heroRepository;
        private final HeroNameConfig heroNameConfig;

        public Hero getHero(String name) {
            return heroRepository.findByName(name).orElse(null);
        }

        public Hero createHero(String name) {
            if (CollectionUtils.containsAny(heroNameConfig.getReservedNames(),
                    Collections.singleton(name))) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        "pick a different name");
            }

            return heroRepository.save(new Hero().setName(name));
        }
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/hero")
    public static class HeroController {
        private final HeroService heroService;

        @GetMapping("/{name}")
        Hero getHero(@PathVariable String name) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(heroService.getHero(name))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        }

        @PostMapping("/{name}")
        Hero createHero(@PathVariable String name) {
            return heroService.createHero(name);
        }
    }
}
```

here is how you might write an `@SpringBootTest` for it:

```java
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.util.TestPropertyValues;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

import java.util.Map;


// tell spring to create a web server for the test
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
// we want the web test client to have a long timeout
// to debug server side code without failing the test due to timeout
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "PT24H")
// for adding an itest-specific configuration file if you need to
@ActiveProfiles("itest")
// setting up our integration test application context
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ReservedNameApplicationITest.Init.class)
class ReservedNameApplicationITest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void test_works() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/api/hero/itest").exchange()
                .expectStatus().isNotFound();
        webTestClient.post().uri("/api/hero/itest").exchange();
        webTestClient.get().uri("/api/hero/itest").exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

    @Test
    void test_reservedWordFails() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/api/hero/admin").exchange()
                .expectStatus().isNotFound();
        webTestClient.post().uri("/api/hero/admin").exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
    }

    static class Init
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(@NonNull ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
            var tag = DockerImageName.parse("postgres")
                    // use alpine for smaller image sizes
                    .withTag("15-alpine");
            // we trust Testcontainers to do its thing with the resource
            //noinspection resource
            PostgreSQLContainer<?> p = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(tag);
            p.start();

            TestPropertyValues.of(Map.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url", p.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username", p.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password", p.getPassword()
            )).applyTo(ctx.getEnvironment());
        }
    }

}
```

a complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/alexanderankin/how-to-do-in-spring/tree/main/testing/integration/simple/reserved-name)

Comment: **1.** Thanks a lot for these good explanations. Actually this class throws error when I run Unit Tests, not Integration tests. But as far as I see, it is normal as this `@SpringBootTest` is also run automatically for Integration Tests, right?

Comment: **2.** On the other hand, do you mean that I should change the annotation from `@SpringBootTest` to `@WebMvcTest` for now even if I do not have any integration test?

Comment: **3.** I will just start to write Integration Test for my Spring Boot app. But I am so confused after reading several articles. So, should I write Integration test without using an in memory database etc and using just mocks ?

Comment: 1) "is it normal for @SBT to run itests" - yes, that is its purpose. 2) changing the annotation would change it from itest to unit test. 3) if you don't have manager to mandate it, then its a matter of preference :)

Comment: No mandatory, but in some articles it is mentioned that connecting a database (in memory, etc) causing the tests takes too long time and for this reason they prefer using some other approaches. So, is the following examples are a proper ones? And if you have any suggestion, could you share with me??? >>>

Comment: https://www.arhohuttunen.com/spring-boot-integration-testing/

Comment: https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-test/

Comment: its usually just worth it to wait that way you know your test is meaningfully testing a real db - https://jschmitz.dev/posts/testcontainers_how_to_use_them_in_your_spring_boot_integration_tests/

Comment: and i wouldn't even use the `@Container` annotation. there is a "start" method on the container class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. There ia also another concept that makes people confused. I am thinking to write Integration Tests for Controller. So, could you point out a proper example approach for that?

Comment: not sure what you mean. if i have to test something in the controller like parsing a specific header, i write a unit test. if i want to test that spring routes requests according to headers per my annotation, i write a full `@SBT` integration test. (no `@DataJpaTest`, no `@WebMvcTest`, just autowire the TestRestTemplate or WebTestClient and make requests and assert that returned values are what we expect, given the test data we set up for ourselves before the test)

Comment: full @SBT integration test sound a proper approach for my situation. Because my purpose is send request and check if the app process the request properly and manipulate data based on this request. So, how should I search such implementation?  Should I use `@SpringBootTest` integration test?

Comment: I think this is what I need, right? >>> https://jschmitz.dev/posts/how_to_test_any_http_client_of_your_spring_boot_application_with_mock_server/

Comment: @binary check out https://github.com/alexanderankin/how-to-do-in-spring/tree/main/testing/integration/simple/reserved-name

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer. I am looking but get an error, and opened new question.  could you pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785824/springboottest-cannot-initialize-postgresql-database