# @SpringBootTest cannot initialize PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I am trying to create database for my Integration Test using `@SpringBootTest` as shown below:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
abstract public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;
}
```

```
class ProductControllerTest extends IntegrationTest {

    @Test
    // @Sql("/create-product.sql")
    void findById() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform((get("/api/v1/products/{id}", 1)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.name", equalTo("TV")));
    }

    //...

}
```

Here is the `application-test.yml` file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
#    url: jdbc:postgresql:13.2-alpine://product
#    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/product
     url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11:1:///product

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    placeholderReplacement: false
    baseline-on-migrate: true
```

I tried several url as shown above, but none of them is working and gives:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:tc:postgresql:11:1:///product
2023-03-20 03:37:26.933 ERROR 26832 --- [    main] SpringApplication                        : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:tc:postgresql:11:1:///product
```

So, what is the problem? Should I use initial sql script or is there any implementation for Flyway?

**Update:** Here is also related dependencies on pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


<!--        Also tried with these -->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.17.6</version>-->
<!--            <type>pom</type>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.17.6</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

Comment: postgres would not accept that jdbc url because it needs to be accepted by testcontainers. is testcontainers on the classpath? additionally, im not sure that is a well-formed jdbc url after adding the `tc:`, e.g. on [this page](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#jdbc-url-examples) there is an example given: `jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///databasename`. i think maybe you meant to put `jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.1:///product`

Comment: sorry, how can I check this -> "is testcontainers on the classpath?"

Comment: you would have had to add it in maven or gradle or somewhere. e.g. [like so](https://github.com/alexanderankin/how-to-do-in-spring/commit/ff0528eece4b1595a54c54fbf56b83085ff2dc84#diff-c50119a1b0e79f860847cb72e78ff3f3c4c7237450b924720e87c1c7468cb35f) - for your case replace "itestImplementation" with "testImplementation"

Comment: ill be honest though, I don't quite know how that url magic works. i just stick to the basic "new XContainer().start()" pattern.

Comment: Do I need to add these 2 lines (for Maven) ? `itestImplementation platform('org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.17.6')
    itestImplementation('org.testcontainers:postgresql')`

Comment: What about using something like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.2-alpine://payment` without needing to add any maven dependency? I also tried it, but not worked

Comment: have to add the dependency. the `jdbc:tc:` part makes it use a separate driver. and they just put the initialization code in the driver itself. and yes - it would look different (<dep...><gro..>org.testcontainers</g...><....><scope>test</scope></dep...>) for maven but yes.

Comment: added 2 dependencies and tried with different urls, and not working :(

Comment: try adding just `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
`

Comment: also - try doing the initializer. because then you will see if it is on the classpath at compile time, as your program will contain references directly to the classes.

Comment: What do you mean with also - try doing the initializer. ?

Comment: I tried only this dependency that you shared, but still not working

Comment: i think you might have to post an mvce (like including your pom.xml) to hopefully get some input from someone who knows maven. but its an older technology. I've only seen gradle at work.

Comment: try adding an initializer like [here](https://github.com/alexanderankin/how-to-do-in-spring/blob/ff0528eece4b1595a54c54fbf56b83085ff2dc84/testing/integration/simple/reserved-name/src/itest/java/org/example/ReservedNameApplicationITest.java#L28) (which [references classes from the library](https://github.com/alexanderankin/how-to-do-in-spring/blob/ff0528eece4b1595a54c54fbf56b83085ff2dc84/testing/integration/simple/reserved-name/src/itest/java/org/example/ReservedNameApplicationITest.java#L61))

Comment: Thanks, actually I shared all the necessary classes, etc. And I added my pom.xml (related part) as Update. Could you have a look at?

Comment: At the last step, it continued after downloading image and applied migrations. Just throw "memory leak error". I will restart PC and retry again. But actually I would like to apply this using my application-test.yml

Comment: Not it's giving "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authTokenFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUtils': Error creating bean with name 'jwtUtils': Injection of autowired dependencies failed"

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the imagen version for postgres. Maybe you can try with a previous version.

Example:

```
<embedded-database-spring-test.version>2.0.1</embedded-database-spring-test.version>
```

Comment: Could you give an example based on my code? I could not understand what is that? I am using Spring Boot.